# changing rev value in ivy.xml using perl/python

Tags: python, xml, perl, ivy

Need to change rev="{rev}" in ivy.xml dynamically right before the build. I was trying to use Perl XML:Simple module but the output was not acceptable. In the dependencies section, I'm getting:

```
<dependencies name="dependency">
  <poi org="ossjava" rev="3.6.0" />
</dependencies>
```

instea of

```
<dependencies>
       <dependency org="ossjava" name="poi" rev="3.6.0"/>
</dependencies>
```

Please help! A Python code snippet will also suffice

Comment: Did you know that ivy supports dynamic revisions natively? "latest.integration" and "latest.release". For more details see : http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile/dependency.html

Answer (score 1):

XML::Simple is ironically the most complex XML module to use. You'd need to specify an empty `KeyAttr` argument.

Anyway, I'd use:

```
use XML::LibXML qw( );

my $qfn = 'ivy.xml';

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $doc    = $parser->parse_file($qfn);
my $root   = $doc->documentElement();

for my $poi ($root->findnodes('//poi')) {
   $poi->setAttribute('rev', process($poi->getAttribute('rev')));
}

$doc->toFile($qfn);
```

Comment: I assumed `poi` lives in the null namespace since didn't specify otherwise.